# Why is my mounted MacFUSE NTFS vol read-only?

Tags: macos, ntfs, volume, macfuse

I got the impression from the [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) site that when you install it and connect an NTFS volume it will be writable. However, the volume I mounted is read only. Here is some of the output of `mount`...

The NTFS external USB drive I'm talking about:

```
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/SATA160 (local, nodev, nosuid, read-only)
```

An OS X format external USB drive (for comparison):

```
/dev/disk3s3 on /Volumes/USB_ext_drive_40_GB (local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
```

Do I need to set something somewhere? Edit a config file?

I'm on OS 10.4 (Tiger).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you also install the [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/) driver?

Comment: No, I didn't know you had to do that. I installed the driver and it works. Thanks.